# Amazon SNS not accepting dolar signs $ on SMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-sns

I'm tryng to publish SMS's with company revenues in Amazon SNS,

when i try to send a message with a dolar sign $ inside body, it just wont send the message or simple erase the signs from message.

the only solution for this issue is when i set a (´) or (`) character before the dolar sign, like scaping in a linux bash or something...

why is this happening? somebody already went through this issue?

Comment: Works for me, testing SMS using the AWS/SNS console.  Have you tried that?  How are you sending the message?

Comment: Hi! i'm also testing with AWS console, when i try to send any message with dolar signs $  it just remove the signs from message...

Comment: wich region do you live? our AWS servers are in USA, and our app is running on Brazil, i don't know if maybe there are restrictions here or in USA SMS technology or something that is blocking the sign and some characters else...

Comment: Tested in `us-east-1` as "transactional" and `us-west-2` as "promotional."  The specific string included a space followed by `$5.00` and another space, surrounded by words before and after, where `$` is ASCII 36 (0x24).  Both were delivered intact.  Have you tested against multiple wireless carriers?

Comment: Possibly related: the [GSM 03.08 character set](https://www.csoft.co.uk/support/character-sets) apparently places the generic currency symbol `¤` at character 36 (0x24) instead of `$`.

Comment: Something strange happened, i think @Michael-sqlbot got a point, when i send a message with the (¤) character, the AWS console sended me a SMS with the dolar sign ($), maybe the console is trying to parse something... in this case especifically it tries to parse a message in a UTF8 charset to ASCII or something...

Comment: I don't know this service, however SMS can be encoded as DefaultGSM(7bit) or UCS(16bit). Check their documentation if you can choose between them. Phone usually changes to UCS encoding as soon as special character is used.
And of course, your input must be in appropriate charset they know to read, parse, and encode properly.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Amazon docs, you can provide:

- 160 GSM characters
- 140 ASCII characters
- 70 UCS-2 characters

We had a problem (Java) which by default uses Unicode strings. We fixed it by doing something like this:

```
final byte[] ascified = messageBody.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);

final PublishRequest request = new PublishRequest()
        .withMessage(new String(ascified, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII))
        .withPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
        .withMessageAttributes(smsAttributes);
```